# Why am I getting a very small number as CNN prediction?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, tensorflow, image-recognition

I created a CNN using Tensorflow to identify pneumonia and sometimes it returns a very small number as a prediction. why is this happening?

[I have attached the link for the dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/namindusanchila/x-ray/data)

Here I how I process and load the data.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )
val_datagen  = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/kaggle/input/chest-xray-pneumonia/chest_xray/chest_xray/train/',
                                                    batch_size=20,
                                                    class_mode='binary',
                                                    target_size=(350, 350)) 

validation_generator =  val_datagen.flow_from_directory('/kaggle/input/chest-xray-pneumonia/chest_xray/chest_xray/val/',
                                                         batch_size=20,
                                                         class_mode  = 'binary',
                                                         target_size = (350, 350))
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/kaggle/input/chest-xray-pneumonia/chest_xray/chest_xray/test/',
                                                         batch_size=20,
                                                         class_mode  = 'binary',
                                                         target_size = (350, 350))
```

And here the Model, compile and fit functions

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # Note the input shape is the desired size of the image 150x150 with 3 bytes color
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(350, 350, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2), 
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'), 
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # Flatten the results to feed into a DNN
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), 
    # 512 neuron hidden layer
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'), 
    # Only 1 output neuron. It will contain a value from 0-1 where 0 for 1 class ('cats') and 1 for the other ('dogs')
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')  
])
```

compile the model

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

model fit

```
history = model.fit(train_generator,
                              validation_data=validation_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch=200,
                              epochs=2000,
                              validation_steps=200,
                              callbacks=[callbacks],
                              verbose=2)
```

The evaluation metrics as followings,
loss: 0.2351 - accuracy: 0.9847

The prediction shows a big negative number for the negative pneumonia, and for positive it shows more than .50.

I have two equations?

1. why I getting a very small number as 2.xxxx * 10e-20
2. why I can't get the following values as null?

   val_acc  = history.history[ 'val_accuracy' ]
   val_loss = history.history['val_loss' ]

I am a still student in machine learning and I really appreciate your effort to solve my question.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange. It seems to me that this is or could be a programming issue. Let me know if I am wrong or right. Generally, questions about programming problems are off-topic here and should probably be asked on Stack Overflow. Here, we focus on the **theoretical, philosophical, social** and **historical** aspects of Artificial Intelligence. Please, take the time to read [our on-topic page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). So, if you think this is not a programming problem, you should edit your post to clarify that.

Comment: Thank you so much let me know and I will remove this question from here and I am really sorry!!!!